# How to access a BitLocker-encrypted drive in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu-16.04, system-administration, bitlocker

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 along with windows 10. I have encrypted my drives using BitLocker. Now my encrypted drives are not visible in ubuntu 16.04. But I want to access my encrypted drives using BitLocker password like windows. How can I do this?

Comment: According to the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), topics that are relevant to stack overflow are: 1) a specific programming problem, or 2) a software algorithm, or 3) software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu not support it nativly but there is some 3rd part free software to do it (Dislocker). There is a lot of articles about this topic on Google. For example here: https://www.m3datarecovery.com/bitlocker/bitlocker-linux/access-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-linux.html

Comment: That M3 Data Recovery article has a link to nonexistent site www.hsc.fr. Dislocker source is at https://github.com/Aorimn/dislocker ,